# Loop through all clickable links selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, loops, click

I'm trying to click each job listing by looping through each one. How can I get to a previous state after I click the link and then click the next link? I tried driver.back(), here I tried driver.get(url) but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import csv
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
driver.maximize_window()  # load web driver
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get('https://www.seek.com.au/data-jobs-in-information-communication-technology/in-All-Perth-WA')

looking_job = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-automation='jobTitle']")
e = []
count = 1
for xx in looking_job:
    get_url = ""
    get_url += driver.current_url

    sleep(3)
    second = xx.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//a[@data-automation='jobTitle'])[{}]".format(count)).click()
    sleep(3)
    count += 1
    driver.get(get_url)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Do you need help with the page transversal as well? A hint for that would be ?page=2 a simple url fix would do that then check if you find no elements.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Can you help me out brother? I understand the the logic but I can't get it to run how I want. I've tried two methods. But neither work how I want them to. I tried getting the current link outside of the loop and then setting up a template format with the current link, but when I run the program there are a lot of issues since it's looping outside of the loop at that point.  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833880/python-transversal-through-all-a-links-selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
looking_job = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-automation='jobTitle']")]
for job in looking_job:
    driver.get(job)
```

Just grab all the links and driver.get to them.